# Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of a mean difference using paired data?

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, meta-analysis, paired-data

Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of a mean difference using paired data (ie. two instruments measuring the same thing). Eg. I have mean1 and SD1, as well as mean2 and SD2. I know the mean difference, but not the SD of the mean difference. In some instances, I have a p-value for the mean difference, so I can back-calculate the SD, but in many cases original papers do not present that data. Thanks!

Guillaume Martel

Comment: If you found the answer helpful you can accept it by clicking on the green tick (US = check-mark) by the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to find the SD pf the $D_i = Y_i - X_i$ because in paired data the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are typically correlated. $Var(D_i)$ depends on the correlation.

Example: We have $X_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = \sqrt{13})$ and 
$y_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma = sqrt{13}).$
Then $E(Y_i - X_i) = E(Y_i) - E(X_1).$

```
set.seed(2020)
e = rnorm(100, 0, 2)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 3) + e
y = rnorm(100, 60, 3) + e
mean(x);  mean(y)
[1] 49.87084       # aprx 50
[1] 59.79931       # aprx 60
mean(y) - mean(x)
[1] 9.928477       # aprx 10
mean(y - x)
[1] 9.928477       # aprx 10 again
```

If $X_i$ and $Y_i$ were independent, then we would
have $Var(Y_i - X_i) = Var(Y_i) + Var(X_i).$ but
this is not true if $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are correlated.

```
var(x);  var(y)
[1] 16.08572      # Small sample: 16.1 is poor est. of Var(X)=13      
[1] 17.69097
var(x)+var(y)
[1] 33.77669
var(y - x)
[1] 25.5832       # smaller than 33.78
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.2428528     # not independent
```

**Addendum.** On getting $S_D$ from P-value of a t test, sample size, $\bar D,$ and the hypotheses tested.
Here is a simulated sample of $n=20$ differences $D_i$ and results of a t test
of $H_0: \mu_D = 0$ vs. $H_a: \mu_D > 0$ to use as a guide. Everything is from R.

```
set.seed(1234)
d = rnorm(20, 1, 1.5)
t.test(d, alte="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 1.8351, df = 19, p-value = 0.0411
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03602716        Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.6240039
```

Step 1: Use P-value and sample size to find the t-statistic. The trouble with this is that some software gives only severely rounded P-values, or if
the P-value is large just say that it's greater than .1 or .2. (Also, for a 2-sided test the P-value is double, so you must halve it and use the correct tail.) In R, `qt` is the quantile function (inverse CDF) of Student's t distribution.

```
qt(1-0.0411, 19)
[1] 1.835076
```

Step 2: Use the t statistic, $\bar D,$ hypothetical value of $\mu_D,$ and $n$ to get $S_D:$
From 
$$T = \frac{\bar D - \mu_D}{S/\sqrt{n}},$$
we have, in this case where $\mu_D = 0$ under the null hypothesis:
$\sqrt{n}\bar D = TS_D.$ So we can get $S_D$ (within rounding error) as below.

```
.624*sqrt(20)/1.835
[1] 1.52077
sd(d)
[1] 1.520711
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. So, to derive the SD of the mean difference, I need more information. Am I correct to assume that I can back calculate it from the p-value from the mean difference? I also have the variance of the median difference. Am I correct to assume that I cannot use a correlation coefficient and its p-value to derive the SD?

Comment: (1) Back calculation works much of the time. See Addendum to my Answer. (2) Don't immediately see how to use $r$ and its P-value to get variance of diff. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: If by $r$ the OP means the before and after correlation there is no problem, as is implicit in the answer. If by $r$ is meant the effect size measure popular with psychologists then conversion may be possible but that would demand a bit of searching on the site.

Comment: By r I meant the Pearson correlation coefficient examining the relationship between two sets of paired measurements (intended to measure the same thing). Let me know if you know how to do this... Many thanks!

Comment: Further to my last comment, I have found this approach: https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_4_6_1_mean_differences.htm, wondering whether this would be appropriate, using the correlation approach mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe you need a new Question with a clear example of the problem you want to solve and a clear question whether the approach in the handbook or some correlation approach is appropriate. It appears to me that the specific difficulty in the current question is due to incomplete/improper presentation of the data in your source.